# computation cannot be performed with standard 32-bit LAPACK

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training my dataset using VGG as below. It worked well without zca whitening, but after adding zca, it cause an error called

> "computation cannot be performed with standard 32-bit LAPACK"

. As you can see, I tried to train the number of batchsize..etc.. to 1, and even just train with 6 images, but it still din not work. What should I do?

Here is my code.

```
import os
from keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers import Input, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras import optimizers
import numpy as np
import time
from PIL import Image 
import csv
import shutil

# 分類するクラス
classes = ['sugi', 'hinoki']
nb_classes = len(classes)

img_width, img_height = 256, 256

# トレーニング用とバリデーション用の画像格納先
train_data_dir = 'dataset/train1'
#validation_data_dir = 'dataset/validation'

# 今回はトレーニング用に200枚、バリデーション用に50枚の画像を用意した。
nb_train_samples = 1998
#nb_validation_samples = 50

batch_size = 32
nb_epoch = 10
gen_tr_batches = 4
folder = './output'
result_dir = 'results'
if not os.path.exists(result_dir):
    os.mkdir(result_dir)
train_imagelist = os.listdir(train_data_dir)

def vgg_model_maker():
    """ VGG16のモデルをFC層以外使用。FC層のみ作成して結合して用意する """

    # VGG16のロード。FC層は不要なので include_top=False
    input_tensor = Input(shape=(img_width, img_height, 3))
    vgg16 = VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_tensor=input_tensor)

    # FC層の作成
    top_model = Sequential()
    top_model.add(Flatten(input_shape=vgg16.output_shape[1:]))
    top_model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    top_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    top_model.add(Dense(nb_classes, activation='softmax'))

    # VGG16とFC層を結合してモデルを作成
    model = Model(input=vgg16.input, output=top_model(vgg16.output))

    return model



def image_generator():
    """ ディレクトリ内の画像を読み込んでトレーニングデータとバリデーションデータの作成 """
    gen_train = (ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255.).flow_from_directory(train_data_dir,
                    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
                    #color_mode='rgb',
                    batch_size=batch_size,
                    shuffle=True))

    gen_tr_x = np.vstack(next(gen_train)[0] for _ in range(gen_tr_batches))

    #train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    #    rescale=1.0 / 255,
    #    zoom_range=0.2,
    #    horizontal_flip=True,
    #    zca_whitening = True)


    g = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255.,
                        zca_whitening=True)
    g.fit(gen_tr_x)

    #validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1.0 / 255)

    train_generator = g.flow_from_directory(
        train_data_dir,
        classes=classes,
        class_mode='categorical')


    #validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
       # validation_data_dir,
        #target_size=(img_width, img_height),
        #color_mode='rgb',
        #classes=classes,
        #class_mode='categorical',
        #batch_size=batch_size,
        #shuffle=True)

    return (train_generator)





# Generator for the network's training generator.



# Actual generator for the network's training.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time.time()

    for the_file in os.listdir(folder):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder, the_file)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                os.unlink(file_path)
        #elif os.path.isdir(file_path): shutil.rmtree(file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    # モデル作成
    vgg_model = vgg_model_maker()

    # 最後のconv層の直前までの層をfreeze
    for layer in vgg_model.layers[:15]:
        layer.trainable = False

    # 多クラス分類を指定
    vgg_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-3, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

    # 画像のジェネレータ生成
    train_generator =  image_generator()


    # Fine-tuning
    history_callback = vgg_model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
        nb_epoch=nb_epoch)
        #validation_data=validation_generator,
        #nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples)

    loss_history = history_callback.history["loss"]
    accuracy_history = history_callback.history["acc"]
    numpy_loss_history = np.array(loss_history)
    numpy_accuracy_history = np.array(accuracy_history)

    f = open("result.csv","w")
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["loss","accuracy"])
    for j in range(len(numpy_loss_history)):
        writer.writerow([numpy_loss_history[j],numpy_accuracy_history[j]])

    vgg_model.save_weights(os.path.join(result_dir, 'finetuning.h5'))

    process_time = (time.time() - start) / 60
    print(u'学習終了。かかった時間は', process_time, u'分です。')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is, it's not a `tensorflow` issue, but rather a `numpy` issue, and I guess that because [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/preprocessing/image.py#L807)'s what's happening when you try to set the `zca` parameter to `True`:

```
    if self.zca_whitening:
        if self.principal_components is not None:
            flatx = np.reshape(x, (-1, np.prod(x.shape[-3:])))
            whitex = np.dot(flatx, self.principal_components)
            x = np.reshape(whitex, x.shape)
```

By default, when you install `numpy`, it tries to find a low level linear algebra library installed on your system, and use that. `LAPACK` is one of them.

`numpy` will use its own code if no library is available. So try installing your `numpy` without any of those libraries as suggested in the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/building.html):

```
BLAS=None LAPACK=None ATLAS=None python setup.py build
```

If that still uses the libraries, try the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228967/compile-numpy-without-intel-mkl-blas-atlas-lapack).

Then, if the above workaround solves your problem, try compiling a 64bit `LAPACK` and compile your `numpy` against it.

Comment: Thank you. So how can I install numpy without that kind of library?

Comment: Hey there, I am trying what you said but I dont know where is the source code for numpy in my computer. Once I feel like I almost found it, the command line said: "This is the wrong setup.py file to run "

Comment: you shouldn't try to find the `numpy` source on your computer, you should follow the installation path given in the docs. The hyperlink is in the answer I gave.

Comment: Yah now that error dissapeared, but there is another error: in g.fit(gen_tr_x) the program raise "Memory error". Is it relevant?

Comment: also this line was mentioned sigma = np.dot(flat_x.T, flat_x) / flat_x.shape[0]

Comment: That means now you're using `numpy`'s implementation, which may take more memory that the `LAPACK`s implementation. Now you should try getting a `numpy` compiled against your custom compiled `LAPACK`, or `BLAS` or whatever. WARNING: it can take you some time to figure out how to do that, but it's worth it.

Comment: also, if an answer helps you, you can upvote and set as accepted answer for us to be motivate to answer your other questions ;)

Comment: first try to figure out how to compile one of these libraries (of your choise, lapack, blas, etc) for your system (OS dependent). Then follow the numpy's compilation doc and give appropriate paths and parameters for it to find your recently compiled library.

Comment: Okay I will try. But 1 question: why we tried to install numpy without LAPACK in the previous time, but now we need to compile it?

Comment: `numpy`s implementation is not efficient at all compared to those other mature libraries. You can test your code with numpy`s implementation, but for large datasets and in production, you definitely need something much heavier than pure numpy.

Comment: Hey, after two days I still cannot find the way. Could you give me some hints?

Comment: To be honest, I think I havent get what you meant by "find your recenly compiled library". Why I have to find it?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463240/how-to-compile-lapack-so-that-it-can-be-used-correctly-during-installation-of-oc

Answer (score 1):

**This answers the more general problem observed when using `lapack` function such as `svd` on very large matrices.**

Instead of:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import svd

a = np.ones((30000,30000))
u,s,v = svd(a) # this fails
```

Use:

```
u,s,v = svd(a, lapack_driver='gesvd') # this DOES NOT fail
```

My official ticket with an example is here:
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/10337