# Keras ImageDataGenerator Fit causes memory leak

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm on Keras 2.2.2 and I'm trying to generate augmentations of my training data with `zca_whitening` and an `ImageDataGenerator`. But when I try to fit the generator (which is mandatory when using `zca_whitening`) the `python` process eats more and more memory (100Gb+) until it gets killed by the system.

This small example can cause the leak:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

def cause_leak():
    idg = ImageDataGenerator(zca_whitening = True)
    random_sample = np.random.random((1, 250, 250, 3))
    idg.fit(random_sample)

cause_leak()
```

**Update**: Yesterday this was marked as a bug in the Keras repository.

Comment: I've already posted it there, too (https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/11058). I just thought applying `zca_whitening` in an `ImageDataGenerator` is such a common task that I can't be the first one observing this and there has to be some kind of misconception on my part..

Comment: Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626572/computation-cannot-be-performed-with-standard-32-bit-lapack

Comment: Also this https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/1531.

Comment: @Kabanus: i post my answer as a comment, np :)

@wottpal: Try to edit your random_sample like below:
`random_sample = np.random.random((1, 32, 32, 3))`
You probably have a out of ram RAM issue (you need mutch ram that the free ram of your PC), the ram usage increment exponentially, so from 32 to 250 you've exponential ram usage.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in this [issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/issues/55) this is not a memory leak as computing Singular Value Decomposition on the matrix with (250 * 250 * 3) i.e., 187000 elements is memory intensive. Unfortunately, there is no immediate work around for this issue as of now as problem lies with the calculation of sigma matrix as mentioned [here](http://%20https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py#L938)