# ValueError: Too large work array required -- computation cannot be performed with standard 32-bit LAPACK on linux server

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, anaconda, svd

When I use `scipy.linalg.svd()` to process a large matrix, the program gives the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LaplacianMatrix.py", line 98, in <module>
    LaplacianInverse = LaplacianPinv(Laplacian)
  File "LaplacianMatrix.py", line 67, in LaplacianPinv
    UL,SL,VL = linalg.svd(Laplacian)
  File "/home/task3/dylan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/decomp_svd.py", line 125, in svd
    compute_uv=compute_uv, full_matrices=full_matrices)
  File "/home/task3/dylan/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/linalg/lapack.py", line 712, in _compute_lwork
    raise ValueError("Too large work array required -- computation cannot "
ValueError: Too large work array required -- computation cannot be performed with standard 32-bit LAPACK.
```

So what can I do to make the code work well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [computation cannot be performed with standard 32-bit LAPACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626572/computation-cannot-be-performed-with-standard-32-bit-lapack)

Comment: it's not a duplicate at all!!! I have exactly the same problem. I want to do SVD on a large matrix and I get the same error

Comment: Any idea how to solve this? Here is my code: `import numpy as np;
from scipy.linalg import svd:

a = np.ones((30000,30000));
u,s,vh = svd(a)` and here my ticket: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/10337

Comment: Thanks, serafeim. Your answer do solve my problem, but I do not  know why this way works either.

Comment: Thanks,@Mike, I have tried this way but failed with many obstacles cause I have no enough authorization  on a linux server.

Comment: @jean-francois why was my answer deleted?

Comment: see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626572/computation-cannot-be-performed-with-standard-32-bit-lapack/56693335#56693335

Answer (score 0):

The LAPACK C lib has 32 bit long signed integers assigned, but your error says you need to work with longer integers. See an in-depth discussion [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5906).

For a sanity check and to make sure this is not a memory related issue try overcommiting:
As sudo run `echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` and then try running again your computation and see if it goes through this time. Make sure also you have enough ram for your computations to go through if you are doing everything on memory.
Check also the answer of this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type).

But your problem is the C lib.