# Unable to allocate array with shape and data type

Tags: python, numpy

I'm facing an issue with allocating huge arrays in numpy on Ubuntu 18 while not facing the same issue on MacOS.

I am trying to allocate memory for a numpy array with shape `(156816, 36, 53806)`
with

```
np.zeros((156816, 36, 53806), dtype='uint8')
```

and while I'm getting an error on Ubuntu OS

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.zeros((156816, 36, 53806), dtype='uint8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (156816, 36, 53806) and data type uint8
```

I'm not getting it on MacOS:

```
>>> import numpy as np 
>>> np.zeros((156816, 36, 53806), dtype='uint8')
array([[[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

       ...,

       [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8)
```

I've read somewhere that `np.zeros` shouldn't be really allocating the whole memory needed for the array, but only for the non-zero elements. Even though the Ubuntu machine has 64gb of memory, while my MacBook Pro has only 16gb.

versions:

```
Ubuntu
os -> ubuntu mate 18
python -> 3.6.8
numpy -> 1.17.0

mac
os -> 10.14.6
python -> 3.6.4
numpy -> 1.17.0
```

PS: also failed on Google Colab

Comment: Are there other processes running in memory?

Comment: hmmm. weird. That shouldn't taking that much memory. How much memory did it occupy on Macos?

Comment: It is very strange. In my MacOs with 16 GB of RAM it runs instantly without any error

Comment: + it should occupy 35GB in ram, theoretically

Comment: on my macos it's not taking memory as expected

Comment: Unlikely, but you don't happen to be running a 32 bit Python interpreter in Ubuntu right?

Comment: @jdehesa i'm running 64bit

Comment: ps: also failed on google colab (edited that in question)

Comment: @ivallesp theoretically yes, but that function shouldn't be allocating zeros

Comment: `np.zeros` does not create a `sparse` matrix.  There maybe a delay in filling in the zeros.  But see https://stackoverflow.com/q/27464039

Comment: It is a long shot, but what is the output of `ulimit` in the Ubuntu box? If it is not "unlimited" try `ulimit -m`.

Comment: @PauloScardine it is unlimited

Answer (score 198, accepted):

This is likely due to your system's [overcommit handling](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting) mode.

In the default mode, `0`,

> Heuristic overcommit handling. Obvious overcommits of address space are refused. Used for a typical system. It ensures a seriously wild allocation fails while allowing overcommit to reduce swap usage. The root is allowed to allocate slightly more memory in this mode. This is the default.

The exact heuristic used is not well explained here, but this is discussed more on  [Linux over commit heuristic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688824/linux-over-commit-heuristic) and [on this page](http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/virtual_memory_settings_in_linux_-_the_problem_with_overcommit/).

You can check your current overcommit mode by running

```
$ cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
0
```

In this case, you're allocating

```
>>> 156816 * 36 * 53806 / 1024.0**3
282.8939827680588
```

~282 GB and the kernel is saying well obviously there's no way I'm going to be able to commit that many physical pages to this, and it refuses the allocation.

If (as root) you run:

```
$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

This will enable the "always overcommit" mode, and you'll find that indeed the system will allow you to make the allocation no matter how large it is (within 64-bit memory addressing at least).

I tested this myself on a machine with 32 GB of RAM.  With overcommit mode `0` I also got a `MemoryError`, but after changing it back to `1` it works:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.zeros((156816, 36, 53806), dtype='uint8')
>>> a.nbytes
303755101056
```

You can then go ahead and write to any location within the array, and the system will only allocate physical pages when you explicitly write to that page.  So you can use this, with care, for sparse arrays.

Comment: this was the case, thank you, do you know where is this variable on mac os?

Comment: This is specifically a feature of the Linux kernel so there isn't nececssarily a direct equivalent on MacOS, though possibly something similar.  I don't think it's as easy on Macs to twiddle kernel settings.

Comment: @Iguananaut what is the exact meaning of the "with care" warning?  ie. What is the worst case scenario of something going wrong with this on an Ubuntu 18 server with GTX 1080 GPU?

Comment: @mLstudent33 For one, this has nothing to do with your GPU, which has its own memory.  All I mean is you can still fill up your memory--every time you write to some page in memory that page (typically 4k bytes) must be committed to physical memory.  So the worst case scenario is you run out of memory.

Comment: @Iguananaut thank you for the clarification.  Indeed I am running into out of memory errors now.

Comment: what is the reason for 1024**3?

Comment: @Iguananaut .  If we provide 1 in /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory will it be iimpacted in any way ?

Comment: @Ravi I'm not sure what you're asking.  Of course changing this parameter has an impact but on what?  You just wrote "it".

Comment: Does this change take effect immediately or do we need to restart our shell or the machine itself?

Comment: It takes immediate effect, but it will not persist beyond reboot without additional measures. Search other questions on how best to persist `/proc/sys` settings on your distribution.

Comment: @Acumenus There are many reasons you could get a `MemoryError`.  The original question was specifically about allocating an array larger than the available physical memory to use as a sparse matrix.  You are better off opening a separate question.

Answer (score 134):

I had this same problem on Window's and came across this solution. So if someone comes across this problem in Windows the solution for me was to increase the [pagefile](https://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/pagefile) size, as it was a Memory overcommitment problem for me too.

Windows 8

1. On the Keyboard Press the WindowsKey + X then click System in the popup menu
2. Tap or click Advanced system settings. You might be asked for an admin password or to confirm your choice
3. On the Advanced tab, under Performance, tap or click Settings.
4. Tap or click the Advanced tab, and then, under Virtual memory, tap or click Change
5. Clear the Automatically manage paging file size for all drives check box.
6. Under Drive [Volume Label], tap or click the drive that contains the paging file you want to change
7. Tap or click Custom size, enter a new size in megabytes in the initial size (MB) or Maximum size (MB) box, tap or click Set, and then tap or click OK
8. Reboot your system

Windows 10

1. Press the Windows key
2. Type SystemPropertiesAdvanced
3. Click Run as administrator
4. Under Performance, click Settings
5. Select the Advanced tab
6. Select Change...
7. Uncheck Automatically managing paging file size for all drives
8. Then select Custom size and fill in the appropriate size
9. Press Set then press OK then exit from the Virtual Memory, Performance Options, and System Properties Dialog
10. Reboot your system

Note: I did not have the enough memory on my system for the ~282GB in this example but for my particular case this worked.

**EDIT**

From [here](https://www.geeksinphoenix.com/blog/post/2016/05/10/how-to-manage-windows-10-virtual-memory.aspx) the suggested recommendations for page file size:

> There is a formula for calculating the correct pagefile size. Initial size is one and a half (1.5) x the amount of total system memory. Maximum size is three (3) x the initial size. So let's say you have 4 GB (1 GB = 1,024 MB x 4 = 4,096 MB) of memory. The initial size would be 1.5 x 4,096 = 6,144 MB and the maximum size would be 3 x 6,144 = 18,432 MB.

Some things to keep in mind from [here](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001293.htm):

> However, this does not take into consideration other important factors and system settings that may be unique to your computer. Again, let Windows choose what to use instead of relying on some arbitrary formula that worked on a different computer.

Also:

> Increasing page file size may help prevent instabilities and crashing in Windows. However, a hard drive read/write times are much slower than what they would be if the data were in your computer memory. Having a larger page file is going to add extra work for your hard drive, causing everything else to run slower. Page file size should only be increased when encountering out-of-memory errors, and only as a temporary fix. A better solution is to adding more memory to the computer.

Comment: @Azizbro I've gone back to the default now but just adjusted the values until out-of-memory error disappeared.

Comment: I've done this and I still get ```MemoryError: Unable to allocate 10.3 PiB for an array with shape (38137754, 38137754) and data type float64```

Comment: This works for me. But we'd better not allocate the virtual memory in the system desk (C:). Otherwise, it is slow when you restart your computer. [Don't say how do I know this, I have done it T.T  T.T]

Comment: @GeorgeAdams it wasn't working on my machine too. I'm working with vs code and noticed that i have to run it as an admin. this worked for me

Comment: My C: do not have enough capacity. And unfortunately allocating more on D: does not solve this issue.

Answer (score 43):

I came across this problem on Windows too. The solution for me was to **switch from a 32-bit to a 64-bit version of Python**. Indeed, a 32-bit software, like a 32-bit CPU, can adress a [maximum of 4 GB](https://techterms.com/help/difference_between_32-bit_and_64-bit_systems) of RAM (2^32). So if you have more than 4 GB of RAM, a 32-bit version cannot take advantage of it.

With a 64-bit version of Python (the one labeled **x86-64** in the download page), the issue disappears.

You can check which version you have by entering the interpreter. I, with a 64-bit version, now have:
`Python 3.7.5rc1 (tags/v3.7.5rc1:4082f600a5, Oct  1 2019, 20:28:14) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]`, where [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] means "64-bit Python".

Sources :

- [Quora - memory error generated by large numpy array](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-deal-with-the-memory-error-generated-by-large-Numpy-Python-arrays)
- [Stackoverflow : 32 or 64-bit version of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405913/how-do-i-determine-if-my-python-shell-is-executing-in-32bit-or-64bit-mode-on-os)

Comment: How do I enter interpreter?

Comment: Solved my problem too. Using Pycharm. Uninstalled 32-bit version, reinstalled 64-bit one, changed project interpreter to the new 64-bit python.

Comment: @Shayan : to enter the interpreter, open a terminal (`Win + R` `cmd`) and type `python -i`.

Comment: I have already `Python 3.7.6 (default, Jan  8 2020, 20:23:39) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32`. My compute overall memory is 16GM and available is 4.4 GM, but I still have the problem.

Comment: @Sht I also still have the problem.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, adding a dtype attribute changed dtype of the array to a smaller type(from float64 to uint8), decreasing array size enough to not throw MemoryError in Windows(64 bit).

from

```
mask = np.zeros(edges.shape)
```

to

```
mask = np.zeros(edges.shape,dtype='uint8')
```

Answer (score 5):

change the data type to another one which uses less memory works. For me, I change the data type to numpy.uint8:

```
data['label'] = data['label'].astype(np.uint8)
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue running pandas in a docker contain on EC2. I tried the above solution of allowing overcommit memory allocation via `sysctl -w vm.overcommit_memory=1` (more info on this [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting)), however this still didn't solve the issue.

Rather than digging deeper into the memory allocation internals of Ubuntu/EC2, I started looking at options to parallelise the DataFrame, and discovered that using [dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/) worked in my case:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('path_to_large_file.csv')
...
```

Your mileage may vary, and note that the dask API is very similar but not a complete like to like for pandas/numpy (e.g. you may need to make some code changes in places depending on what you're doing with the data).

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue with numpy by trying to have **image sizes of 600x600 (360K)**, I decided to **reduce to 224x224 (~50k)**, a reduction in memory usage by a factor of 7.

`X_set = np.array(X_set).reshape(-1 , 600 * 600 * 3)`

is now

`X_set = np.array(X_set).reshape(-1 , 224 * 224 * 3)`

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

```py
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

prof = ProfileReport(df, minimal=True)
prof.to_file(output_file='output.html')
```

worked for me

Comment: Thanks for sharing suggestion. The input of function is Pandas DataFrame or matrix generated by Numpy? If DataFrame, what was the maximum row and column?