# MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (200, 20, 244, 244, 3) and data type float64

Tags: python, memory-management, keras, deep-learning, python-3.5

I was trying to run a training module from a Github repo located [HERE](https://github.com/liorsidi/ViolenceDetection_CNNLSTM). I'm running it on a cloud server, but I don't know why after some rounds, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 229, in <module>
    classes=classes, use_augs=use_augs, fix_lens=fix_lens)
  File "run.py", line 165, in hyper_tune_network
    classes=classes)
  File "run.py", line 111, in get_generators
    classes=classes)
  File "/home/code/DatasetBuilder.py", line 221, in get_sequences
    X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=seq_length, padding='pre', truncating='pre')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/keras/preprocessing/sequence.py", line 61, in pad_sequences
    x = (np.ones((num_samples, maxlen) + sample_shape) * value).astype(dtype)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 214, in ones
    a = empty(shape, dtype, order)

    MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (200, 20, 244, 244, 3) and data type float64
```

Frist, what does it mean? Is there any ways to fix it? What's the solution?

Comment: That's 5.3 GB of memory you're trying to allocate, on top of whatever else the program has allocated at that point in time.

Comment: Use a (significantly) smaller array :)

Comment: How much memory does the server instance have? Depending on the server size and how many other variables you have, it's definitely possible that you are exceeding the memory available. I ran `sys.getsizeof(x) / 1e6` with your size in the error and got 5715.45616, which means that your variable `x` is taking 5gb of memory

Comment: Thanks guys. I see, I have to check the server's memory. @CristiFati is there anything I can do in the code to decrease the array size?! I guess it should be this number?

Comment: cast your arrays to float16 or float8 type, maybe it fitted in the memory

Comment: @leo Can you show how to do it? `X = pad_sequences` in DatasetBuilder.py

Comment: if X is a numpy array, you can do  ' X = X.astype(np.float16)'

Comment: I didn't look at the source code. I only gave a general advice. Don't know what's the array purpose and whether it can be shrunk.

Comment: @leo I changed the code reflecting that: `X = pad_sequences(X, maxlen=seq_length, padding='pre', truncating='pre', dtype='float16')`...but still got the same error: `MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (200, 20, 244, 244, 3) and data type float16`

Comment: then you need a system with more Memory. or you need to use smaller data set, or resize your images to 32x32 for example. Deep learning especially for image and video is no joke, we don't have all the Google computers to experiment whatever we  want :)

Answer (score -4):

It has something to do with how linux handles RAM overcommits (I assume you're running linux). If you're requesting too much, your process will be killed or you get an error as you describe. As **root**, you can try:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

This will let you request as much as you want. If you request too much, you'll still get an out of memory error, but this will let you use larger arrays.

Comment: Consider adding the whole explanation while giving credits to the original author. https://stackoverflow.com/a/57511555/9871400