# How to increase Jupyter notebook Memory limit?

Tags: python, numpy, memory, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am using jupyter notebook with Python3 on windows 10. My computer has 8GB RAM and at least 4GB of my RAM is free.

But when I want to make a numpy ndArray with size 6000*6000 with this command:
 `np.zeros((6000, 6000), dtype='float64')` 
I got this : `Unable to allocate array with shape (6000, 6000) and data type float64`

I don't think this could use more then 100MB RAM.
I tried to change the number to see what happens. The biggest array I can make is (5000,5000). Did I make a mistake in estimating how much RAM I need?

Comment: It seems to be a limitation hardcoded on your OS. I am not sure about the windows environment, but there is solution stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type that seems to be addressing the same problem on a ubuntu. I suggest you try that one.

Comment: @nima: 6K*6K floats (8 bytes each) will be 36 million * 8 bytes = only **288MB**, which will be fine on most laptops with >= 4GB. But that other question is about a 3D array of total size 283 GB, i.e. 1000x larger and >> physical memory of most laptops.

Comment: The obvious way to check how much memory the numpy ndarray actually takes is to run under plain Python console (not Jupyter), create the ndarray, and see how much memory was allocated. Moreover if it works under console and fails under Jupyter, then you know it's due to Jupyter or its configuration.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Jupyter notebook has a default memory limit size. You can try to increase the memory limit by following the steps:

1. Generate a config file using:

   ```
   jupyter notebook --generate-config
   ```
2. Open the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file situated inside the `jupyter` folder and edit the following property:

   ```
   NotebookApp.max_buffer_size = your desired value
   ```

   Remember to remove the `#` before the property value.
3. Save and run the Jupyter notebook.
   It should now be able utilize the set memory value.
   Also, don’t forget to run the notebook from inside the Jupyter folder.

---

Alternatively, you can simply run the notebook using below command:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.max_buffer_size=your_value
```

Comment: How do I check if the notebook started with the right config file loaded?

Comment: Not sure if something has changed since, but this does not seem to answer does not seem to be correct. As the name suggest, the "max_buffer_size" restricts a buffer, not the overall memory usage. And it appears to be the buffer of the HTTP server (tornado).

Comment: How do we know which value to put ? I mean.. how do you calculate it to be the best and what things should you consider?

Comment: `The Jupyter folder is in your home directory, ~/.jupyter.`

Comment: I don't understand how to run the notebook inside of the .jupyter folder, I don't find him in the folder list through the Notebook folder view. How do you do it ?

Comment: That didn't work for me, you'll just add a limit to your configure.

Comment: Will this information be in the form of bytes, kilobytes, megabytes, gigabytes, or will it look like 100 MB or say 10 GB?

Answer (score 8):

For Jupyter you need to consider 2 processes:

1. The local HTTP server (which is based on Tornado)
2. Kernel process (normally local but can be distributed and depends on your config).

**[max_buffer_size](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/pull/748/files)** is a Tornado Web Server setting, corresponds to the Maximum amount of incoming data to buffer and defaults to 100MB (104857600). (https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html)

Based on this [PR](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/3829/files), this value seems to have been increased to 500 MB in Notebook.

Tornado HTTP server does not allow to my knowledge to define the max memory, it runs as a Python3 process.

For the kernel, you should look at the command defined kernel spec.

An option to try would be this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type)