# Why is my laptop struggling with large data sets? 16gb RAM defeated by a 1.5gb csv

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science, ram, processor

I just started a new job and have been given a Dell XPS 13 7390 laptop and it is really struggling with big data files / processing.

I'm currently working with a 1.5gb csv and I get a memory error when I try to open it with Python in a Jupyter Notebook.

> *Error tokenizing data. C error: out of memory*

I was sure I'd opened files like this with ease on my personal laptop, a 10 year old Macbook, so i tested it on the same file and *it opened*.

Why is my Dell laptop struggling despite having lots of RAM available? Could settings be adjusted to allocate more memory to Jupyter Notebooks? What tests could I run to look into this further?

Hardware details below. The obvious difference is processor speed - does that explain it?

**Dell laptop**:

Ram- 16gb

Processor- Intel Core i7-10510U CPU @ 1.80GHz

**Macbook**:

Ram- 4gb

Processor- 2.7 GHz Intel Core i7

Code used to open the file:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
data.shape
```

The shape = (2250493, 218)

Comment: Have you tried watching your ram in task manager while it opens?

Comment: Can you share the code you used to open the file?

Comment: @AMC code added.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57948003/jupyter-notebook-memory-limit

Comment: @AwesomeCronk memory usage is averaging 10% and peaked at 23% when I ran the code

Comment: thanks @ctenar this looks useful

Comment: @ctenar I tried updating the config file and ran command line update but neither have work.

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 32.0 KiB for an array with shape (4096,) and data type int64

Comment: Hm, too bad. I presume you have made sure you installed the 64-bit version of Python and also started the Jupyter-kernel from scratch to be sure no other data is lingering around in memory. Have you tried doing the same operation outside of a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: @ctenar somehow I had 32bit python installed... I've switched to 64bit and it works fine. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had 32bit python installed... I've switched to 64bit and it works fine