# Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset of sales with 400K + of lines, and i need to execute a pivote below to bring for order line all SKUs in order, put SKUs in columns . I need make it for all orders, because after that i will create another table with these data.

However i get the error below:

```
ValueError: Unstacked DataFrame is too big, causing int32 overflow
```

This is the first time that i apply this method in a big dataset, and i will need to scale that for more bigest datasets.

This is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from pandas import *
import os
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.read_csv('sales.csv')
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates()

df1.index=df1['ORDER_ID']
df3 = df1.assign(col=df1.groupby(level=0).SKU_ID.cumcount()).pivot(columns='col', values='SKU_ID').reset_index()
```

There are some way to execute that in ranges and concat that results? I still dont find way to do that.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61757170/python-unstacked-dataframe-is-too-big-causing-int32-overflow

Comment: do you have sample data to recreate this? you can try dask - https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/. i tried with some large data from http://eforexcel.com/wp/downloads-18-sample-csv-files-data-sets-for-testing-sales/ but could not recreate it.

Comment: Sure, i will share dataset with you.