# How do I limit the amount of RAM Jupyter Notebook is allowed to use?

Tags: python, memory, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I'm currently running some machine learning models that requires quite some pre-processing and such. I have 16GB RAM in my computer, but I don't want it to exceed 90%. Is there a way I can limit jupyter notebook its memory usage? For example, assign it max 10GB? Currently it will just keep using RAM until it reaches 100%, which makes some processes crash.

I tried looking for a setup file of jupyter notebook, but the file 'jupyter_notebook_config.py' does not contain a parameter to set the max. allowed RAM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase Jupyter notebook Memory limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58146531/1431750)

Comment: @aneroid very late reply but yes, it did. Thanks!