# Google Cloud Notebook VM's - High Memory Machine, Kernel Crashing on Memory Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, linux-kernel, jupyter-notebook

I'm using GCP's Cloud Notebook VM's. I have a 200+ gb RAM VM running and am attempting to download about 70gb of data from BigQuery into memory using the bigquery storage engine.

Once it gets to around 50gb the kernel crashes --

Tailing the logs, `sudo tail -20 /var/log/syslog` - here's what I find:

```
Dec  2 13:35:57 pytorch-20200908-152245 kernel: [60783.550367] Task in /system.slice/jupyter.service killed as a result of limit of /system.slice/jupyter.service
Dec  2 13:35:57 pytorch-20200908-152245 kernel: [60783.563843] memory: usage 53350876kB, limit 53350964kB, failcnt 1708893
Dec  2 13:35:57 pytorch-20200908-152245 kernel: [60783.570582] memory+swap: usage 0kB, limit 9007199254740988kB, failcnt 0
Dec  2 13:35:57 pytorch-20200908-152245 kernel: [60783.578694] kmem: usage 110900kB, limit 9007199254740988kB, failcnt 0
Dec  2 13:35:57 pytorch-20200908-152245 kernel: [60783.585267] Memory cgroup stats for /system.slice/jupyter.service: cache:752KB rss:53239292KB rss_huge:0KB mapped_file:60KB dirty:0KB writeback:0KB inactive_anon:0KB active_anon:53239292KB inactive_file:400KB active_file:248KB unevictable:0KB
Dec  2 13:35:57 pytorch-20200908-152245 kernel: [60783.612963] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
Dec  2 13:35:57 pytorch-20200908-152245 kernel: [60783.621645] [  787]  1003   787    99396    17005      63       3        0             0 jupyter-lab
Dec  2 13:35:57 pytorch-20200908-152245 kernel: [60783.632295] [ 2290]  1003  2290     4996      966      14       3        0             0 bash
Dec  2 13:35:57 pytorch-20200908-152245 kernel: [60783.642309] [13143]  1003 13143  1272679    26639     156       6        0             0 python
Dec  2 13:35:58 pytorch-20200908-152245 kernel: [60783.652528] [ 5833]  1003  5833 16000467 13268794   26214      61        0             0 python
Dec  2 13:35:58 pytorch-20200908-152245 kernel: [60783.661384] [ 6813]  1003  6813     4996      936      14       3        0             0 bash
Dec  2 13:35:58 pytorch-20200908-152245 kernel: [60783.670033] Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 5833 (python) score 996 or sacrifice child
Dec  2 13:35:58 pytorch-20200908-152245 kernel: [60783.680823] Killed process 5833 (python) total-vm:64001868kB, anon-rss:53072876kB, file-rss:4632kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Dec  2 13:38:07 pytorch-20200908-152245 sync_gcs_service.sh[806]: GCS bucket is not specified in GCE metadata, skip GCS sync
Dec  2 13:39:03 pytorch-20200908-152245 bash[787]: [I 13:39:03.463 LabApp] Saving file at /outlog.txt
```

I followed this guidance and allocated 100gb of RAM [How to increase Jupyter notebook Memory limit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57948003/how-to-increase-jupyter-notebook-memory-limit) but it's still crashing at around 55gb. e.g., `53350964kB` is the limit in the logs.

How can I utilize the available memory of my machine? Thanks!

## Tacking on what worked - changing this config setting:

`/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/system.slice/jupyter.service/memory.limit_in_bytes` to a higher number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see here "Cgroup out of memory" means that instance has sufficient memory and the process that is being killed in a cgroup. For visualized workload this can be possible as docker containers can cause this issue.

a) To identify the cgroup

system-cgtop

b) Check the limit of the cgroup

cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/[CGROUP_NAME]/memory.limit_in_bytes

c) Adjust the limit, please adjust by editing configuration file of POD, memory limit for Docker Container. Update the limit for raw cgroup

echo [NUMBER_OF_BYTES] > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/[CGROUP_NAME]/memory.limit_in_bytes

Comment: Thanks, going to give this a shot