# Changes to Jupyter Notebook max buffer size config come undone

Tags: memory, terminal, jupyter-notebook, config, reset

I was getting a memory error when I ran a notebook which concatenated several large databases:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 93.1 MiB for an array with shape (9, 1356250) and data type float64
```

I applied the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57948003/how-to-increase-jupyter-notebook-memory-limit), and it worked (yay!). Basically, I generated the config file, modified `NotebookApp.max_buffer_size` to double the size, saved it, and voilà, everybody's happy.

However, I tried it again this morning and the notebook started giving me the same error again. I tried reopening and saving the config file, changing the default as well as the buffer size, regenerating the config file and making the same changes, and entering

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.max_buffer_size=double_value
```

from the terminal, but nothing seems to work. Any idea what might be going on? Thanks!