# Kernel Restarting Issue for Paddle OCR

Tags: jupyter-notebook, kernel, restart, paddle-paddle, paddleocr

The kernel for mynotebook.ipynb appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

```
from paddleocr import PaddleOCR, draw_ocr

ocr = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang='en', use_gpu=False)

result = ocr.ocr(img_path)
```

I am trying to run paddle ocr in my machine & the kernel just stops whenever I try to run `ocr.ocr()`

Comment: You can monitor the ram allocated to the jupyter notebook, maybe refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57948003/how-to-increase-jupyter-notebook-memory-limit to increase memory if it's the issue

Answer (score 0):

Paddle Ocr contains heavy computations,it will not work in localhost jupyter notebook. Try Colab Instead

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).