# How do I increase Jupyter Notebook memory limit with the VS Code extension?

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code, memory, jupyter-notebook

**The Problem**

I'm working with large data structures, but I'm finding that I'm running into the following error. As an example, running this code:

```
np.zeros((6867151, 20, 4))
```

Results in an error stating:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[64], line 1
----> 1 np.zeros((6867151, 20, 4))

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 4.09 GiB for an array with shape (6867151, 20, 4) and data type float64
```

I know that I'm running into an artificial limit because my PC has 32 GB of RAM, and only 32% of which was being utilized at runtime.

**What I've tried**

This question has [seemingly been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57948003/how-to-increase-jupyter-notebook-memory-limit), but they don't seem to be using the VS Code extension for Jupyter Notebook (as I am). As such, I'm not quite sure how to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the following code

```py
import os
os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"]="TRUE"
```

Comment: Didn't do anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in the link in your post? Also can you provide a reproducible example.   Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)