# Unable to allocate array with shape (1482535, 67826) and data type int64

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, scipy

I am trying to store scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix of shape (1482535, 67826) into a dataframe but I am getting an error as below. I am running on Google Cloud Platform with 4CPU's , and 208 GB memory. I can't increase my memory more. How can I solve this issue? Any suggestions are appreciated.

```
type(x_train_bow_name)`
scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix







   data1 = pd.DataFrame(x_train_bow_name.toarray())`




        ----------------------------------------------------------------- 
        ----------
        MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent 
        call 
        last)
       <ipython-input-16-283fa4dd2dd6> in <module>
         ----> 1 data1 = pd.DataFrame(x_train_bow_name.toarray())

                /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist- 
         packages/scipy/sparse/compressed.py in toarray(self, order, out)
            1022         if out is None and order is None:
       1023             order = self._swap('cf')[0]
       -> 1024         out = self._process_toarray_args(order, out)
       1025         if not (out.flags.c_contiguous or 
      out.flags.f_contiguous):
            1026             raise ValueError('Output array must be C or 
         F contiguous')

        /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in 
           _process_toarray_args(self, order, out)
                1184             return out
             1185         else:
            -> 1186             return np.zeros(self.shape,  
          dtype=self.dtype, order=order)
         1187 
        1188 

     MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (1482535, 67826) 
      and data type int64
```

Comment: are you running a 64bit python?

Comment: Hey! This seems a memory overcommitment issue. Check [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type) where the same issue was solved for numpy. Let me know if this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Everything is pointing that it is an [Overcommitting Memory](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting) issue.

Please take a look of the following [link](https://engineering.pivotal.io/post/virtual_memory_settings_in_linux_-_the_problem_with_overcommit/) where is very well explained the virtual memory settings in Linux and the problem with Overcommit.

The two parameters to modify the overcommit settings are `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` and `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio`.

`/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`
This switch knows 3 different settings, but in your case I think you could use the value =`1`

1: Classic example is code using sparse arrays and just relying on the virtual memory consisting almost entirely of zero pages.

The setting can be changed by a superuser:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

The default value is `0`

`/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio`
This setting is only used when `overcommit_memory = 2`, and defines how many percent of the physical RAM is used. Swap space goes on top of that. The default is “50”, or 50%.

The setting can be changed by a superuser:

```
echo 75 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio
```

Also please take a look at the following [post](https://www.iditect.com/how-to/58686879.html)

Answer (score 0):

The way to read sparse scipy matrixes in pandas is:

```
pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(my_sparse_matrix)
```

This creates a DataFrame with sparse dtypes. Sparse dtypes are of the form `pd.SparseDtype("float", np.nan)`

By doing my_sparse_matrix.toarray() you are undoing the "sparsity" of it.