# MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (118, 840983) and data type float64

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting the following error:

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (118, 840983) and data type float64

in my `python` code whenever I am running a python `pandas.readcsv()` function to read a text file. Why is this??

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("LANGEVIN_DATA.txt", delim_whitespace=True)
```

Comment: What about the error message confuses you? It seems to imply to me that there's not enough space in memory to hold the entire csv at one go.

Comment: 118 by 840983 for 8 bytes of float64 data should be less than 1GB; how big is your system memory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to allocate array with shape and data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type)

Comment: Try using the `chunksize` parameter for `read_csv`. Set it to e.g. `chunksize=1000`.

Comment: @PV8 the accepted answer quotes "Obvious overcommits of address space are refused". Unless my calculation is incorrect or the OPs system has very low memory for today's standards, this does not appear to be a case of a memory overcommit.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh This is the weird thing that I have 16 GB of only 0.8GB used, as it is a new PC in the office. I runned the same code on my own PC and it worked normally. Thank you..

Comment: @MKhalil interesting. is your python a 32 bit process in the office? try running the following. `import platform; platform.architecture()`

Comment: Yupe it is a 32 bit process, the code worked using the comment down below. Thanks again

Comment: @MKhalil in that case, my recommendation is, get your office to install and use python 64 bit. 32 bit comes with severe memory restrictions. Your company *will* suffer down the line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MemoryError` means, you file is too large to readcsv in one time, you need used the `chunksize` to avoid the error.

just like:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("LANGEVIN_DATA.txt", delim_whitespace=True, chunksize=1000)
```

you can read the official document for more help.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html