# MemoryError: Unable to allocate X for an array with shape (x, y) and data type float64

Tags: python, pandas, memory

I'm facing a MemoryError while concatenating dataframes and couldn't find an answer in the similar threads ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58910947/memoryerror-unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-118-840983-and-data-type-flo), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type?rq=2), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316767/how-can-i-explicitly-free-memory-in-python#:%7E:text=According%20to%20Python%20Official%20Documentation%2C%20you%20can%20explicitly%20invoke%20the%20Garbage%20Collector%20to%20release%20unreferenced%20memory%20with%20gc.collect().%20Example%3A)). The idea is to retrieve data from nested `json` files and append it into a dataframe :

#### Example code

```
path = 'C:\Desktop\Data'

extension = 'json'
json_list = glob.glob(path + '\\*.{}'.format(extension))

voltages = []
powers = []

# Initialize a list to store memory usage
memory_usage = []

for i,j in enumerate(json_list):
    f = open(j)
    temp_file = json.load(f)
    ii = create_volt_df_from_json(temp_file)
    jj = create_power_df_from_json(temp_file)
    voltages.append(ii)
    powers.append(jj) 
    del ii, jj
    
    gc.collect()
    
df_volt = pd.concat(voltages, axis = 1).groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum()
df_cons = pd.concat(powers, axis = 1).groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum()
```

Functions `create_volt_df_from_json` and `create_power_df_from_json` open a `json` file and retrieve and clean the data of intrest (i.e., 'id', 'timestep', 'values') for the multiple keys. The script runs perfectly and gives the expected result when working with a limited amount of files (e.g., max 5000). Running the code for a directory that contains 5830 files returned :

#### Error message

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 41.3 GiB for an array with shape (1084422, 5112) and data type float64
```

**How could I tackle this issue?** Further, the algorithm/script has to run on a website which will retrieve the data directly from an Azure datalake container, meaning the amount of files will largely exceed 10.000 json files..

*(To keep the question somewhat concise, I haven't added the functions but can add them in case it helps to solve the issue.)*

Comment: Something that may help is transforming variables to types that use less memory. I solved a similar problem before by transforming variables that were read as float by Pandas and didn't actually need to be float, so I transformed them to int8 or int16. Of course, this may help reduce the problem, but at some point you are going to run into the memory limit again. Maybe try using Pyspark instead of Pandas? This may help: https://saturncloud.io/blog/managing-memory-in-pyspark-how-to-drop-dataframes-effectively/

Comment: You might be able to get away by concatenating that data into `df_volt`/`df_cons` as you're reading the files so Pandas doesn't need to allocate another block of memory to copy things to, but that will only scale so far. I'd probably just plonk the data into a local SQLite database and query it.

Comment: What is the distribution of the sizes of your Json files?

Comment: Thank you for the comments Lfppfs and AKX.
@ifly6, this highly depends on the data provider, some directories have 50MB files while other directories have 500MB files. Similar for the amount of files in one directory, it could be 100 files, 1000, 10000. or more..

Comment: Pandas can only work with all the data loaded. Considering using either `dask` or an SQL data base to execute whatever it is you need done. If you are doing mere IO it is possible to rewrite.