# MemoryError((462855, 4998), dtype('uint8'))

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert my categorical variables into category dtype. But I'm getting these errors:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (462855, 4998) and data type uint8

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred

KeyError: MemoryError((462855, 4998), dtype('uint8'))
```

My code is:

```
def get_dummies(df, column):
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(df_categ, prefix=column, prefix_sep='-', drop_first=True)
    df = pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1)
    df.drop(column, axis=1, inplace=True)
    return df

for i in df_categ.columns:
    df_categ[i] = df_categ[i].astype('category')
    df_categ = get_dummies(df_categ, i)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to allocate array with shape and data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type)

Comment: @E.Zeytinci It tells me to change the overcommit mode from 0 to 1. But that's for Linux, and I'm using Windows 10. I'm not sure if you could overcommit memory in Windows 10. Please tell me if there's a way.