# What causes python memory error using fillna()

Tags: python, dataframe, out-of-memory, numpy-ndarray, fillna

I am getting the following error

> numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate array with shape (1329, 22474) and data type float64

This is my code:

```
interactions_df = pd.DataFrame(list(DB[USER_COLLECTION].find({})))
interactions_full_df = interactions_df.groupby(['personId', 'contentId'])[
    'eventStrength'].sum().apply(smooth_user_preference).reset_index()
users_items_pivot_matrix_df = interactions_full_df.pivot(index='personId',  # edited: interactions_train_df
                                                         columns='contentId',
                                                         values='eventStrength').fillna(0)
users_items_pivot_matrix = users_items_pivot_matrix_df.as_matrix()
users_ids = list(users_items_pivot_matrix_df.index)
```

In `USER_COLLECTION`, I have 30009
documents, and 4 columns: `_id, personId(string), eventStrength(double), contentId(int32)`, I tried to settings to increase ram but it didn't work, still couldn't figure it out.

update:
After setting custom virtual memory on windows by maximum memory 80000 MB and initial size 5500 MB, and reboot the system, it still have memory error.

Comment: What OS are you working on ?

Comment: Are you using python 32-bit or 64-bit? What operating system are you on? Are you using any special develeopment environment (e.g. Anaconda)?

Comment: how much RAM is there on your system? Duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type), maybe

Comment: Your computer is trying to allocate 238 MB with that operation, not that much.

Comment: I am working on Windows 8.1.

Comment: After setting custom virtual memory on windows by maximum memory 80000 MB and initial size 5500 MB, and reboot the system, it still have memory error.