# Pandas Pivot Table Returns MemoryError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe where I am looking to aggregate on multiple columns (7 to be exact) and return the sum of multiple columns (4).  The dataframe is 172k rows with 13 columns and takes up 13.2MB (full details below).

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 172038 entries, 0 to 172037
Data columns (total 13 columns):
index              172038 non-null int64
processing_date    172038 non-null int64
mgr_name           171910 non-null category
mgr_code           171937 non-null category
sub_mgr_name       133271 non-null category
sub_mgr_code       133287 non-null category
acct_id            172038 non-null int64
product_id         172038 non-null int64
fx_rate_usd        172038 non-null float64
settle_date_qty    172038 non-null float64
settle_date_mv     172038 non-null float64
seg_memo_qty       18956 non-null float64
restricted_qty     810 non-null float64
dtypes: category(4), float64(5), int64(4)
memory usage: 13.2 MB
```

I then try to pivot it with the following:

```
client_grp_cols = ["processing_date", "mgr_name", "mgr_code", "sub_mgr_name",\
                      "sub_mgr_code", "acct_id", "product_id"]

client_sum_cols = ["settle_date_qty", "settle_date_mv", "seg_memo_qty", "restricted_qty"]


df_clients = df_client.pivot_table(index=client_grp_cols,
                                   values=client_sum_cols,
                                   aggfunc='sum')
```

I then get the following error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 237. PiB for an array with shape (266838394019915520,) and data type int8
```

Can someone help me understand how this happens and how to remedy?  I understand pivot table can be heavy on memory but I didn't expect it to be this bad.  I know I can switch to dask but I would really like to try to stay in pandas (in particular since my base dataframe is only 13mb and no where near my PCs memory limits I don't think I should have to do that).

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to allocate array with shape and data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type)

Comment: @jorijnsmit its definitely helpful - thank you.  im just really surprised that my 13MB file ends up that big after pivoting.  Ive never had this issue with a pivot table before and while i knew i was indexing / grouping by more columns than i usually do i wasnt expecting it to blow up memory like this.  whats going on under the hood with pivot table and group by that causes this?  without changing page sizes is there a way to handle something like this in pandas?  thx again.