# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.00 MiB for an array with shape (131072,) and data type int64

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

When I'm trying to read the data I'm getting the following error.
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.00 MiB for an array with shape (131072,) and data type int64

Please find the code that I have used

```
print("creating the dataframe from data.csv file..")
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',', 
                       names=['movie', 'user','rating','date'])
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
print('Done.\n')

# we are arranging the ratings according to time.
print('Sorting the dataframe by date..')
df.sort_values(by='date', inplace=True)
print('Done..')
```

Please find the attached image for your reference.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to allocate array with shape and data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type)

Comment: Not data tyes, I'm reading 8 billion records.

Comment: If you are trying to read 8 billion records into RAM I would recommend you use a database and SQL to process your data.