# How to fix a memory error when filtering a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I get a memory error while doing a simple filtering on a dataframe. Never had this issue before until windows 10 was reinstalled on my laptop.

I tried a workaround from [Unable to allocate array with shape and data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type), and changed the page file size. Besides I reinstalled my 32-bit python with 64-bit python.

My csv file is not super huge, around 600 MB, my RAM is 16 GB. My code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
quant = df['a'].quantile(0.995)
df = df[df['a']<quant]
```

In the end I get this error `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 171. MiB for an array with shape (3, 7483698) and data type float64`

What is the nature of this issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Using dask data frame can split your data frame into smaller pandas dataframe across your cpu cores. This will enable parallel computing before dask combine the result.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
#Run dask.read_csv() which is quite similar to pandas.read_csv
df = dd.read_csv('file.csv')
#Use — .compute() — to initiate calculation
df = df[ df['a'] < dd['a'].quantile(0.995) ].compute()
#The output from using .compute() is a pandas dataframe
df
```

Source:

1. https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html

Comment: I would prefer not to use Dask since it handles badly dropna and all other sorts of things. I don't think this is an issue with actually not having memory but with memory allocation

Comment: I think it has something to do with the number of columns which says 7,483,698. Have you used a pandas data frame with this many number of columns before? On a separate note, the .compute() function converts a dask data frame into a pandas dataframe. Therefore, the output df in the end is a pandas data frame. Let me what you think.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you explained how the code you provided answers the question.

Comment: Done. Thanks ppery!

Answer (score 0):

So basically the answer is to properly uninstall Python 32-bit and install Python 64-bit.