# AI Platform Notebooks: MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.16 GiB for an array - with 100 disk space in GCP

Tags: pandas, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am trying to load a 1 GB Pandas Dataframe in GCP AI Platform with a 100 GB disk and 15GB RAM virtual machine but I have the following error:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.16 GiB for an array with shape (20, 7762852) and data type object
```

Do you know why the allocation does not execute while the Virtual Machine is a 100 gb disk for 15 gb RAM ?

```
df_event = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(os.getcwd() + '/data/lead_inscrit_train.csv.gz',
                     compression='gzip',
                     sep=';',
                     quotechar='"',
                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
                     dtype=str,
                     parse_dates=["date"]
                    ),
                  pd.read_csv(os.getcwd() + '/data/lead_inscrit_test.csv.gz',
                     compression='gzip',
                     sep=';',
                     quotechar='"',
                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
                     dtype=str,
                     parse_dates=["date"]
                    )]
                , axis=0)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type try changing /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory and restart kernel