# memory issues for sparse one hot encoded features

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scipy, sparse-matrix, amazon-sagemaker

I want to create sparse matrix for one hot encoded features from data frame `df`. But I am getting memory issue for code given below. Shape of `sparse_onehot` is  (450138, 1508)

```
sp_features = ['id', 'video_id', 'genre']
sparse_onehot = pd.get_dummies(df[sp_features], columns = sp_features)
import scipy
X = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(sparse_onehot.values)
```

I get memory error as shown below.

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 647. MiB for an array with shape (1508, 450138) and data type uint8
```

I have tried `scipy.sparse.lil_matrix` and get same error as above.

Is there any efficient way of handling this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what OS do you have? does this help maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type ?

Comment: I am using aws sgaemaker instance type ml.t2.medium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting to `True` the [`sparse` parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

> sparsebool, default False
> Whether the dummy-encoded columns should be backed by a SparseArray (True) or a regular NumPy array (False).

```
sparse_onehot = pd.get_dummies(df[sp_features], columns = sp_features, sparse = True)
```

This will use a much more memory efficient (but somewhat slower) representation than the default one.

Comment: Thanks it solves the error. Later I am able to convert it into `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
`