# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 21.7 GiB for an array with shape (53940, 53940) and data type float64

Tags: python, memory, precision

I am getting the error "MemoryError: Unable to allocate 21.7 GiB for an array with shape (53940, 53940) and data type float64" when I am performing the below function.

```
def precisision(col):
    fp=col.sum(axis=0)-np.diag(col)
    tp=np.diag(col)
    presision=tp/(tp+fp)
    print (presision)
ad=precisision(df["depth"])
```

Diamonds dataset
data set:-https://github.com/siddheshkadam21/Data-Extraction-one/raw/main/diamonds-m.csv

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64964570/memoryerror-unable-to-allocate-8-27-gib-for-an-array-with-shape-323313-3435/64966122#64966122

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to allocate array with shape and data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type)

Comment: Please search for the error message online before asking a very similar question as others that have been answered before! As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Welcome!