# How to work with big WAV files in Python without getting memory error?

Tags: python-3.x, memory, out-of-memory, soundfile

When working with Python's `soundfile` for reading and writing audio `WAV` files that are longer than 9 minutes (size > 500 MB) I am getting a memory error ("cannot allocate 1.1 GBi"). How can I work with such big files without splitting them into smaller files (e.g. in Audacity)? Why without splitting? to detect effects of my processing after long duration runs (e.g. after continuous processing of > 9 minutes), in which history is important.

In general, how do I extend Python runtime memory in order to allow working with big files, including loading them and writing them to the hard-drive?

See also: [Unable to allocate array with shape and data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type)

Comment: In some applications I can split WAV files, writing them part by part and clearing memory on the fly, while saving context variables between subfiles. But there should be a much more convenient solution to work with big files without such tricks.

Comment: This post may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type