# MemoryError: Unable to allocate __ GiB an array with shape ___ and data type object

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have pandas dataframe that contains data about some business processes . it contains the process_id ,employee_name , actions and timestamp of the action and date of the action . i wrote a function that takes the process_id for any given process calculate the time difference between two actions for each employee who did an action on the specified process ,  and return the result as a dataframe . then the returned data frame is appended to another dataframe which includes the working time for employees for all the processes . here is the code i wrote  :

```
def work_time_per_employee_per_process(input_df) :
    """
    this function takes a dataframe as an argument , it calculates the working time for each employee per process by finding 
    the time difference between the the timestamp of the claim action or release and the timestamp of the hold , cancelled or complete
    action . It returns a dataframe with five arguments . process_id which is a unique identifier of the process
    username which is the username of the employee , employee_full_name which indicates the full name of the employee
    working_time which indicates the time the employee worked in seconds ,
    and the date which indicates the date of the action
    """
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['process_id','user_name', 'employee_full_name','working_time' , 'date'])
    for integer in range(len(input_df)) :
        if ((input_df.action.iloc[integer] == 'Claim' or input_df.action.iloc[integer] == 'Release') and
            (input_df.action.iloc[integer + 1] == 'Back to Claiming Pool' or 
            input_df.action.iloc[integer + 1] == 'Hold' or
            input_df.action.iloc[integer + 1] == 'Cancelled' or
            input_df.action.iloc[integer + 1] == 'Complete') and 
            input_df.action_done_by_username.iloc[integer] == input_df.action_done_by_username.iloc[integer + 1]):
            df = df.append({
                'process_id' : input_df.process_id.iloc[integer] ,
                'user_name' : input_df.action_done_by_username.iloc[integer] ,
                'employee_full_name' : input_df.action_done_by_fullname.iloc[integer] ,
                'working_time' : int((pd.Timestamp(input_df.action_timestamp.iloc[integer + 1]) - pd.Timestamp(input_df.action_timestamp.iloc[integer])).total_seconds()) ,
                'date' : input_df.action_date.iloc[integer]
            }
            ,ignore_index=True)
    
    return df
```

```
def working_time_per_employee(dataframe) :
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    dataframe_process_id_unique_list = dataframe['process_id'].unique().tolist()
    for pid in dataframe_process_id_unique_list :
        df = df.append(work_time_per_employee_per_process(dataframe.loc[dataframe.process_id==pid]))
    return df
```

When i run working_time_per_employee i get a memory error .

i tried the approach mentioned in [Unable to allocate array with shape and data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type) . but it didn't solve the issue . i also saw some other threads and some of the answers suggests to upgrade python from 32bits to 64bits but the python installed on my machine is already 64bits . some also suggested to convert the datatypes of the dataframe i tried it and it didn't work . I am using windows 10 machine with 16GB of RAM and using jupyter notebook . Also , the original dataframe contains only 81 rows . My question is why are these two functions consuming alot of memory? I know that iteration  consumes resources but the size of my data is small so why is this happening ?.Also, is there something I can do with my code to process the data while consuming less memory ?

Comment: What is the shape in this case?  Knowing that could help us understand if the code is working like expected or not.  What is the traceback exactly?  Knowing that would also help us by seeing what line the error is occurring at.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by modifying working_time_per_employee function to yield a generator instead of a returning a dataframe . so the function became

```
def working_time_per_employee(dataframe) :
    """
    this function takes a sample dataframe as an argument , then it creates a list of the the unique process_id . it then
    yeilds a execute work_time_per_employee_per_process function and yields a generator of the results
    """
    dataframe_process_id_unique_list = dataframe['process_id'].unique().tolist()
    for pid in dataframe_process_id_unique_list :
        yield work_time_per_employee_per_process(dataframe.loc[dataframe.process_id==pid])
```

and then create another function to iterate through the generator and return a dataframe which looks like this :

```
def convert_generator_to_pandas_dataframe(gen) :
    """this function takes a dataframe generator , and returns the dataframe stored in the generator
    """
    df = pd.DataFrame() 
    for temp_df in gen :
        df = df.append(temp_df)
    return df
```