# How to solve Memory Error when running PyMC3 model

Tags: python-3.x, out-of-memory, hierarchical-data, montecarlo, pymc3

I have the following pymc3 (3.8) hierarchical model, where

- y (dependent variable) is a 1313x1
- x (level 1 predictors) is a 1313x2
- z (level 2 predictors) is a 1313x3 matrix

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    
    gamma_0_0 = pm.Normal("gamma_0_0", mu=0, sigma=10)  
    gamma_k_0 = pm.Normal("gamma_k_0", mu=0, sigma=10, shape=x.shape[1])

    gamma_0_j = pm.Normal("gamma_0_j", mu=0, sigma=10, shape=z.shape[1])
    gamma_k_j = pm.Normal("gamma_k_j", mu=0, sigma=10, shape=(z.shape[1], x.shape[1])) 

    # Model error
    u_0_j = pm.Normal("u_0_j", mu=0, sigma=10) 
    u_k_j = pm.Normal("u_k_j", mu=0, sigma=10, shape=x.shape[1]) 

    r_ij = pm.Gamma("r_ij", alpha=9, beta=4)


    beta_0_j = pm.math.dot(z, gamma_0_j) + gamma_0_0 + u_0_j
    beta_k_j = pm.math.dot(z, gamma_k_j) + gamma_k_0 + u_k_j

    y_hat = pm.math.dot(x, beta_k_j.T) + beta_0_j

    # Likelihood
    y_like = pm.Normal("y_like", mu=y_hat, sigma=r_ij, observed=y)

with model:
    step = pm.NUTS()
    trace = pm.sample(draws=500, chains=2, tune=200, discard_tuned_samples=True, random_seed=SEED, step=step)
```

When I draw only 200 samples (tune=100) from the posterior, the model works fine. However, when I increase the samples to 500 (tune=200), the following error comes up:

numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 12.8 GiB for an array with shape (2, 500, 1313, 1313) and data type float64

Absent the issue that the model does no longer runs, I don't understand why the array shape in the error report is (2, 500, 1313, 1313). 2 could be the number of chains, 500 the number of samples, and 1313 the length of y. But why is it not (2, 500, 1313)?

I know that this error can probably be worked around by allocating more memory as explained here ([Unable to allocate array with shape and data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type)) but I am seeking a more sustainable solution.

I use Windows10 (32GB RAM), Anaconda 3 and Python 3.8