# Pandas - Merging dataframes - MemoryError: Unable to allocate

Tags: python, pandas

I've got two dataframes:
Dataframe `df_transactions` has the column `ip_address`
And dataframe `df_ip` has the columns `lower_bound_ip_address`, `upper_bound_ip_address` and `country`.

I'm joining these dataframes to get the country of the ip address checking if `df_transactions.ip_address` is between `df_ip.lower_bound_ip_address` and `upper_bound_ip_address`.

The code below works in a subset of the data:

```
a = df_transactions.ip_address.values
bh = df_ip.upper_bound_ip_address.values
bl = df_ip.lower_bound_ip_address.values

i, j = np.where((a[:, None] >= bl) & (a[:, None] <= bh))

pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([df_transactions.values[i], df_ip.values[j]]),
    columns=df_transactions.columns.append(df_ip.columns)
)
```

But when I try to do it for the entire dataframe, I'm getting the following error.
Do you know the better way to solve this ?

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_23472/1585362522.py in <module>
      3 bl = df_ip.lower_bound_ip_address.values
      4 
----> 5 i, j = np.where((a[:, None] >= bl) & (a[:, None] <= bh))
      6 
      7 pd.DataFrame(

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 15.5 GiB for an array with shape (120000, 138846) and data type bool
```

Thanks !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type

Comment: kindly provide sample input dataframe, with expected output dataframe.