# MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.82 GiB for an array with shape (108, 2260668) and data type float64

Tags: python, pandas, windows, dataframe, out-of-memory

When running the code:

```
loan_data = pd.concat([loan_data, loan_data_dummies], axis = 1)
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.82 GiB for an array with shape (108, 2260668) and data type float64
```

I tried these steps :

```
    Windows 10

Press the Windows key
Type SystemPropertiesAdvanced
Click Run as administrator
Under Performance, click Settings
Select the Advanced tab
Select Change...
Uncheck Automatically managing paging file size for all drives
Then select Custom size and fill in the appropriate size
Press Set then press OK then exit from the Virtual Memory, Performance Options, and System Properties Dialog
Reboot your system
```

per the instructions here ; [Unable to allocate array with shape and data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type)

I allocated 8000 MB to drive C and 2000 to drive D, not sure how to allocate my memory of 11000 MB to stop the error from happening?

Comment: You are running out of system RAM not disk space.

Comment: is there a solution for it?

Comment: Probably, can you post the code that is generating the error?

Comment: added, just concatenation of 2 dfs

Comment: Can you add where you define `loan_data` and `loan_data_dummies`?

Comment: Is this a 64-bit Python or a 32-bit Python? 1.82GiB might be too big for a 32-bit Python if there are other things allocated already.

Comment: 3.8.8 (default, Apr 13 2021, 15:08:03) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=8, micro=8, releaselevel='final', serial=0) , the 64 version