# Unable to allocate 11.6 GiB for an array with shape (1554122468,) and data type int64

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, merge

I am getting kind of weird error when I tried to Merged my Dataframe files which has 930333 rows & 21 columns in FullRaw1 as well 56078 rows & 2 columns in CustTag at the time of merge i'm getting error of
"Unable to allocate 11.6 GiB for an array with shape (1554122468,) and data type int64"

```
    FullRaw1 = pd.merge(FullRaw1, CustTag, how ='left', on ='Customer_No').drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: This means your datasets are too big for your computer's memory.

Comment: @mozway Ram memory??

Comment: Yes it's requiring too much RAM

Comment: @mozway  Any other way to sort this problem??

Comment: No, you can only solve this by increasing memory capacity or, the more feasible solution, by splitting up your dataframe in more manageable chunks.

Comment: See this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58686879/18454578), I guess this can solve your problem.

Comment: This is interesting as I'm seeing a similar error on a server that is not likely running low on memory. When I RDP into the machine it is showing 500 out of 512GB RAM free but I get....

```numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.14 GiB for an array with shape (24, 35088, 500) and data type float64
```

Python 3.9.12, Pandas 1.5.0, numpy 1.23.3