# Avoid Memory Error When Assigning a Large Array to Two Different Variables

Tags: python-3.x, memory

I am assigning a (500000,) array of type float64 to two different variables. How can I mangae to avoid the following error message?

```
newx = newy = np.zeros((new_num,))
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.81 MiB for an array with shape (500000,) and data type float64
```

Note:
I use a 64 version of python that is installed on a Windows 10 machine and am running the script on visual studio code. Since I don't have admin permission, I cannot change Windows settings as mentioned in this link [Unable to allocate array with shape and data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to allocate array with shape and data type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type)

Comment: Sure, the part relevant to my case was the Windows case. Since I am not admin on my machine, I would rather not mess with the settings as suggested by one of the answers. I can try it as temporary solution only and change settings back to their original values. Thank you for directing me to this link!

Comment: Also note that you should be using the *64-bit version of Python* (on the off chance you're not already doing so, or you might inadvertently be picking up a 32-bit version).  It's certainly worth double-checking :)

Comment: The number of variables is irrelevant. There is only one array, that's the problem. Also, this has nothing to do with memory leaks,  memory management...

Comment: Thank you for editing tags. I do use 64-bit version of the python.