# How to solve memory error? Should I increase memory limit?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, memory, out-of-memory

I was loading this but it says error.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

userMovie = np.load('userMovieMatrixAction.npy')

numberUsers, numberGenreMovies = userMovie.shape

genreFilename = 'Action.csv'
genre = pd.read_csv(genreFilename)
```

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.63 GiB for an array with shape (487495360,) and data type float64
What can I do? It's driving me crazy.

Comment: use swap if not enough ram

Comment: Are you in Linux or Windows?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type for a solution (lower down there's a windows solution as well)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the program runs out of memory, it seems like an issue with [overcommit handling](https://www.etalabs.net/overcommit.html) of your operative system. If you are in Linux, you can try to run the following command to enable "always overcommit" mode, which can help you load the 3.63GiB npy file with `numpy`:

```
$ echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

Answer (score 2):

1. First things first you don't need float64 you can save this as float32 using the casting pandas function you can find here
   https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html ..even if you were working on a neural network you would try to save as float32, you will reduce your byte footprint in this way.
2. You may need to build a generator to allow the data to be loaded into memory when needed in chunks not entirely in memory as you are trying to do.
   links to Python guide
   https://docs.python.org/3/howto/functional.html#generators
   Kaggle notebook using generators
   https://www.kaggle.com/code/vbookshelf/python-generators-to-reduce-ram-usage-part-2/notebook

You are  starting to build a recommender system as far I can see ....