# Jupyter Notebook error: Unable to allocate 8.12 GiB for an array with shape (22370, 389604) and data type uint8 (tried changing memory but still fail)

Tags: python, memory, jupyter-notebook

I'm building a training and test set on Jupyter Notebook but I always receive the following memory error:

"Unable to allocate 8.12 GiB for an array with shape (22370, 389604) and data type uint8"

I followed the advice from other stack overflow members (which is increasing the jupyter notebook memory limit by typing **c.NotebookApp.max_buffer_size = 100000000000** in the **jupyter_notebook_config.py** file located in the directories when I installed my anaconda navigator package) however, I'm still encountering the same error. I'm not so sure what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

For Jupyter you need to consider 2 processes:

1. The local HTTP server (which is based on Tornado)
2. Kernel process (normally local but can be distributed and depends on your config).

**[max_buffer_size](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/pull/748/files)** is a Tornado Web Server setting, corresponds to the Maximum amount of incoming data to buffer and defaults to 100MB (104857600). (https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpserver.html)

Based on this [PR](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/3829/files), this value seems to have been increased to 500 MB in Notebook.

Tornado HTTP server does not allow to my knowledge to define the max memory, it runs as a Python3 process.

For the kernel, you should look at the command defined kernel spec.

I would try the following:

1. Increase physical memory
2. Optimize how you read the data in the Pandas Dataframe?
3. Try this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type)