# How to install 64 bit lapack for Scipy/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

I am trying to run an ICA using sklearn.decomposition.FastICA but I am getting this error:

`ValueError: Too large work array required -- Computation cannot be performed with standard 32 bit lapack`

Googling around found me this thread
[computation cannot be performed with standard 32-bit LAPACK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49626572/computation-cannot-be-performed-with-standard-32-bit-lapack). It suggested that I should compile numpy/scipy with a 64 bit lapack. However, the thread didn't go into detail as to how to do that. Can someone guide me through installing numpy/scipy with a 64 bit lapack? If possible, I'd like to install it on one of my conda environments. I don't have sudo on the machine.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: All common install-methods should bring binaries including Intels MKL or OpenBLAS which should work. The question is: how did you do this and what potentially went wrong? Are you using 32-bit python? As you can use venv or condas *environment* i don't see a problem in regards to no-sudo.